# Periodically dump the content of a map to a file in java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have 2 JSON files which contain over 1 million Objects .

I have to compare each object from both the files and then write to a file if there is a diff for any object. (Each object is identified by a key and that key is written to a file).

Currently i am using ExecutorService and doing comparisons using multiple threads and writing mismatches to a common ConcurrentHashMap.

The map is dumped to a file in the end .

I would like to update the file periodically rather than waiting for the entire execution to complete.

In case if i wish to write to the file once in every 2 minutes, how can i achieve this.

I am familiar that this could be done using another thread but could not actually understand how exactly to implement along with ExecutorService.

Comment: Kindly post your code so that problem resolution will be quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    // some code to execute every 2 minutes
}, 0, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Hi AlmasB, 

I already have an executor . Can i run the timer thread along with that executor .

Also if i use newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor , how would i use it along with another executor . 

Should i place it after i invoke all the tasks using first executor ?

Comment: Yes, you can use as many as you want. However, you may want to use the following: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool%28int%29 so that it handles threads for you. You simply queue up tasks by calling scheduleAtFixedRate